# ItextSharp 401 error (Image issue)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3, itext, http-status-code-401

I'm having some trouble using iTextSharp in MVC3.

I am creating a header/footer with some images and it works fine locally but when i upload it to my server it returns a 401:

> The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. 
>     Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.
>
> Exception Details: System.Net.WebException: The remote server returned an error: (401) Unauthorized.

My header/footer code:

```
public override void OnEndPage(iTextSharp.text.pdf.PdfWriter writer, iTextSharp.text.Document document)
    {

        //Include the header image
        //System.Web.HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/image.jpg");

        iTextSharp.text.Image HeadImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/image.jpg"));
        HeadImg.ScalePercent(50f);
        HeadImg.SetAbsolutePosition(document.PageSize.Width - 60f - 72f, document.PageSize.Height - 36f - 216.6f);

        //Include the footer image/text
        iTextSharp.text.Image FootImgMS = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/image.jpg"));
        FootImgMS.ScalePercent(50f);

        iTextSharp.text.Image FootLeftImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/image.jpg"));
        FootLeftImg.ScalePercent(50f);

        Phrase FootText = new Phrase("Phone: " + Tel, FontFactory.GetFont("verdana", 10));

        Paragraph LeftFoot = new Paragraph();
        LeftFoot.Add(new Chunk(FootLeftImg, 0, 0));
        LeftFoot.Add(new Chunk(Chunk.NEWLINE));
        LeftFoot.Add(new Phrase(FootText));

        //Create header table
        PdfPTable PDFTab = new PdfPTable(1);

        //Create footer table
        PdfPTable PDFFootTab = new PdfPTable(2);

        //Create header cell
        PdfPCell PDFCell1 = new PdfPCell(HeadImg);
        PDFCell1.Border = 0;

        //create footer cells
        PdfPCell PDFFootCell1 = new PdfPCell(LeftFoot);
        PDFFootCell1.PaddingTop = 35;
        PdfPCell PDFFootCell2 = new PdfPCell(FootImgMS);
        PDFFootCell1.Border = 0;
        PDFFootCell2.Border = 0;
        PDFFootCell1.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_LEFT;
        PDFFootCell2.HorizontalAlignment = Element.ALIGN_RIGHT;

        //Add cells to tables
        PDFTab.AddCell(PDFCell1);
        PDFTab.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width;
        PDFFootTab.AddCell(PDFFootCell1);
        PDFFootTab.AddCell(PDFFootCell2);
        PDFFootTab.TotalWidth = document.PageSize.Width - 80;

        //Write out header table
        PDFTab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 0, document.PageSize.Height, writer.DirectContent);

        //Write out footer table
        PDFFootTab.WriteSelectedRows(0, -1, 40, 60, writer.DirectContent);

        //set pdfContent value
        pdfContent = writer.DirectContent;

        pdfContent.MoveTo(30, document.PageSize.Height - 145);
        pdfContent.LineTo(document.PageSize.Width - 40, document.PageSize.Height - 145);

    }
```

I'm almost certain it has something to do with the images but I just can't work out what it should be.

Any help would be apreciated :)

Comment: Can you access the image directly in a browser without hitting the 401 error?

Comment: Yes i can. I also tried it without the dynamic variables (Logo and Tel) but I still get the 401 when loading the PDF.

Comment: You mean that the 401 error is raised when **downloading** the PDF, not when **creating** the PDF? Is the PDF file correctly created on the server? Are the visibility permissions set correctly on the folder where the file is created?

Comment: Sorry, I meant when creating the PDF. I don't set the permissions for the server, my colleague does but he assures me it is set correctly (I have gone back to him to double check). I was just wondering if I had done anything glaringly daft with my code.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your image is located at the root of your web application, try setting a tilde in front of your application relative paths :

```
iTextSharp.text.Image HeadImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("/image.jpg"));
```

becomes

```
iTextSharp.text.Image HeadImg = iTextSharp.text.Image.GetInstance(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/image.jpg"));
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I tried that and unfortunately get the same problem.